# scale 14 bit word to an 8 bit word

Tags: verilog, fpga, sampling, uart

I'm working on a project where I sample a signal with an ADC, that represents values as 14 bit words.  I need to scale the values to 8 bit words.  What's a good way to go about this in general.  By the way, I'm using an FPGA so I'd like to do it in "hardware" rather than a software solution.  Also in case you're wondering the chain of events will be: sample analog signal, represent sample value with 14 bit word, scale 14 bit word to 8 bit word, transmit 8 bit word with UART to PC COM1.

I've never done this before.  I was assuming you use quantization levels, but I'm not sure what an efficient circuit for this operation would be.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: +1 Good example of how a seemingly complex problem ("scale" to a different number of bits) can have a _very_ simple solution (drop the least significant bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need an add and a shift:

```
val_8 = (val_14 + 32) >> 6;
```

(The `+ 32` is necessary to get correct rounding - you can omit it but you will get more truncation noise in your signal if you do.)

Comment: I don't understand why you add 32.  It seems like your final 8 bit value will just be offset by 4.  How does that prevent truncation noise.  Also, since you brought it up, and I'm just learning this, is truncation noise similar to quantization noise.  Can I model them the same way?  Thanks.

Comment: Since we're dividing by 64 with the right shift we add 32 to get rounding to nearest rather than truncation towards zero. This gives a uniform distribution of error and evenly spaced step sizes in the output. And yes, truncation noise is rather like quantisation noise.

Comment: Sorry.  Like I said in my other response, when I was working out the operation on paper trying to understand the concept I tried examples of scaling 8 bits to 5 bits.  So I guess in that example I should have added 4 to apply your technique to cancel out noise?  Makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just drop the six lowest resolution bits and call it good, right? But I might not fully understand the problem statement.

Comment: OK. I see.  so basically it scales the value by a factor of 8 or 1/8 and drops off the remainder.  I should have worked that out on paper before I asked.  I also should have brushed up on binary multiplication and division.  Thanks.

Comment: Shifting by 6 bits is equivalent to dividing by 64, not 8.

Comment: Sorry, when I was working this out by hand I used the example of scaling 8 bits to 5 bits just to get the concept but make it easier.  But I got point.  Thanks

Comment: If you have lines for each bit in hardware, I think you just simply ground the lowest six.

In software, in C, you might do something like this:

`unsigned char new_val = (old_val >> 6);`

Answer (score 2):

Paul's algorithm is correct, but you'll need some bounds checking.

```
assign val_8 = (&val_14[13:5]) ?  //Make sure your sum won't overflow
                         8'hFF :  //Assign all 1's if it will
                         val_14[13:6] + val_14[5];
```